# Rails 4 with Omniauth 1.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am trying to implement omniauth with ruby on rails, while I am merely learning this just in case I might need it on the future, I have found furstration on implementing the examples I have readen so far, since some of them use old gem or because API has change since.

There are so many errors on going that I don't even know where to begin and the documentation on github isn't enough or I haven't been able to descifer it, so the question is kind of forbidden, is there a real good tutorial step by step that I can follow, it doesn't matter if it uses mongo or devise as long as it works, thanks in advance.

Comment: [This Railscast should be enough](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth)

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling to much, but my mistake was something not mentioned in the video, I hadn't set the URL callback, thus giving me some wacko errors, plus the key and secret were not on a correct format, but thanks for your assistance.